# Django - If country field equals United States send ajax request to set state selector to a tuple of US states

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

In my django form I want to make some type of ajax/jquery request so that if the user selects "United States" as their country, the state field automatically turns into a drop down with all of the states (choices= STATE_CHOICES). How can I accomplish this within Django? I saw DAJAX in search results but am hesitant as I feel like there should be a pretty easy way to do this. Thanks in advance.

#### Update:

Was able to get some of this done with ajax. When the user looses focus on the country field, it sends the data in that field to the corresponding view.

```
    //JQUERY CODE
$("#id_country").focusout(function()
    {
        var country = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            URL: '/accounts/register/',
            data: {
                country: $(this).attr('value')                    
            }
            });

    });`
```

This is the view it gets sent to. It never recgonizes that it is an ajax call. It always falls into the else statement unless of course the user submits the form.

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES

def register(request):
form = RegistrationForm()
form_pref = UserInfoForm(request.POST)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)     
    if form.is_valid():   
        form_pref = UserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=UserInfo())            
        if form_pref.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()                
            user=UserInfo.objects.create(user_id=new_user.id)            
            form_pref = UserInfoForm(request.POST, instance = user)  
            form_pref.save()   
    if form_pref.is_valid():
        form_pref.save(commit=False)

if request.is_ajax():
   ajax= "AJAX"
   country = request.POST.get('choices')  
    # I tested out in the shell and this line below changed the choices for me           
   form_pref.fields['state_province']._set_choices(STATE_CHOICES)   

else:

    form = RegistrationForm()
    form_pref = UserInfoForm()       
    country = "test"
 forms = (form, form_pref)

return render_to_response('register_form.html', {'form':form,'form_pref': form_pref,'forms':forms, 'ajax':ajax, 'country':country}
```

Comment: Why do you need an extra AJAX call to retrieve this information? This should be done on client-side only.

Comment: To make use of the U.S. states local flavor add on STATE_CHOICES which allows me to call a tuple of state choices without having to statically enter in the state information myself. Your right, I could do it all client side but seems wasteful if I can use django to do it for me. That is of course depending on long it takes me to figure this out :).

Comment: `$(this).attr('value')` is **bad**. Use `$(this).val()` instead!

Comment: I think what he was suggesting is that you should have the dropdown list of States already on the page but hidden (generated by Django local flavors).  Then when they select US as country you un-hide the dropdown.  A lot less overhead to achieve the same thing.  And overall probably a better design of displaying the States information.  Ask if you have questions on how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you have HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header in your ajax request? Your version of Javascript library may not set up it. Test it with debug tools of browser. View the doc please: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a post method for that AJAX call... the request.is_ajax() should be an if...else statement inside of the if request.method == "POST" statement.